# Installed certbot and started to receive port 80 error

Tags: nodejs, letsencrypt

I'm running node.js server on ubuntu20.04 (without nginX)
I'm attempting to use SSL for the first time.
I installed certbot with 'certbot certonly --standalone'

My node server was set to ports 9080 (http)/9089 (https) for Dev and using these ports everything seemed to work.

As i'm now entering production, I changed the node server ports to 80/443, which all seemed to work initially. About 30 minutes later, I start to see the following error:

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::80

Is certbot also using port 80, if yes why and how can I rectify?
My node webserver is for api calls only, so as an option, I can continue to run node on a non standard port. Is it normal to do this?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

```
root@ubuntu01:~# netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      549/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      537445/sshd: /usr/s
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      949/mongod
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      537445/sshd: /usr/s
tcp6       0      0 :::9080                 :::*                    LISTEN      675537/node /home/j
tcp6       0      0 :::9089                 :::*                    LISTEN      675537/node /home/j
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           549/systemd-resolve
```

I also have a socket server running on the same port as http (now set to 8080), should this make any difference.

```
socket.server = require('socket.io').listen(http_server);
socket.start();
```

Comment: what does netstat -tupln show?

Comment: Updated question with netstat

Comment: Appreciate it, taking a look now.

Comment: To answer your certbot port question: If you're using any Certbot with any method other than DNS authentication, your web server must listen on port 80 so only use DNS auth for the cert validation and it wont listen on port 80, thats what I do as I have it on my FW and use port 80 and 443 already and your second question of should this matter for port 8080, nope

Comment: If certbot listens on port 80 (as I think you are suggesting) then are you saying I cannot  run node server on port 80 also ?

Comment: It only runs on 80 if you use any other verification method but DNS, if you always use DNS to verify to get your cert then certbot will not use 80. Just always use DNS cert verification option. On my FW, the CP uses port 80 and 443 and I use certbot on it and have no issues as I use DNS verification always.

Comment: Appreciate your help on this, thanks. When I set up cerbot I used the -- standalone option, is this where I went wrong ? Could you tell me how I can set up ' DNS verification' for cerbot pls ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113660/discussion-between-simplifixed-and-jet).

Comment: Hi again, Tried 'certbot -d example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly' and two options appeared in the shell. I tried both options but I was greeted with no TXT